# Can I temporarily disable automatic orientation changes in my Activity?

Tags: android

Can I temporarily disable automatic orientation changes in my Activity? I want to do this when my app does some background internet communication.

Answer (score 0):

It easier to implement activity lifecycle correctly then try to fight it. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainAnObject